# In the Minecraft 1.7 update, you can turn off ambience and environment, but what noise is environment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On the 'sound' options, added new in 1.7, You can turn off ambience and environment. I know what ambience is (The scary, jumpy cave sounds) but what is environment? Is it the same thing? Is it totally different? Is it similar?

Comment: rain and thunder perhaps?

Comment: I think that rain and thunder are part of the 'weather' option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same thing

[image]

The screenshot shows Ambient/Environment, rather than two different options. So it's whatever you prefer to call it.

Answer (score -4):

Environment? Ambience and environment are the same thing.

In the minecraft options sound folder, ambience is cave and weather.

Comment: See aman's answer. Folder structure is not a good argument, a screenshot of the settings in question is.